# How strong would a magnetic field need to be to go nuclear

Tags: electromagnetism, nuclear-physics

A sufficiently strong magnetic field would rip electrons out of their orbits triggering a chain reaction causing a nuclear reaction, with that said, how strong would it need to be before I would have to start worrying about this?

Comment: Even exceedingly strong magnetic fields do not rip electrons out of their orbits. Are you thinking of strong electric fields? Also we routinely rip all the electrons off atoms, e.g. in ion colliders, and it does not cause any fusion reactions.

Comment: Ripping electrons out of their orbits is called ionization. Positively charged nuclei will repel each other not be more attracted to each other. Going nuclear requires either smashing the nuclei together or knocking them apart with neutrons.

Answer (score 3):

[There has been modelling and simulation work](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.73.629) on atoms in magnetic fields up to $10^{13}$ Gauss, the kind of environment you get around neutron star surfaces. As was first noted by [Ruderman](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.27.1306), superstrong magnetic fields make electron orbitals near-cylindrical and enable superstrong atom chains - quite the opposite of a nuclear chain reaction. Later research has questioned whether this works for all atoms, but it appear that infinite chains are possible for light atoms.

The reason this does not rip apart atoms is that electrons are not accelerated further away, but into looping orbits ([Landau levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization)). In an electric field a wayward electron will gain energy the further it moves towards the positive pole. That might lead to it hitting other atoms, ionizing or heating them up leading to further [breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown) - but this does not happen for magnetic fields even at very high densities (it might cause [other weird instabilities](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269313001895), but not anything explosive).